# How do you create a page that queries a legacy database in umbraco and secure it with Active Directory?

Tags: umbraco, extending

I was interested in using Umbraco for an internal project.  Can I use it to query a legacy database and display the results within the CMS?  Can this page that I created be limited security wise via Active Directory (I read you can use AD in Umbraco.  Hope it's true.)

Am I going outside of what Umbraco is supposed to be for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [wiki article about Active Directory authentication](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers/active-directory-membership-provider) here:

Yes, you can query a legacy database. Umbraco uses Razor or Web User Controls in MasterPages so you can do anything you'd normally do in ASP.NET in Umbraco as well.

In the future, if you have more questions, it might be a better idea to post to [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org) instead, you will get faster and better answers than here on SO.